# Is there anyway in python to count syllables without the use of a dictionary?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

CMUdict works for the english language, but what if I want to count the syllables of content in another language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the language.  This may sound like an obvious answer, but it all comes down to how the orthography is designed.  In English, syllables are pretty much independent of how the words are written, so you'd need a dictionary.  Many other languages are like this.

Certain other languages though (like (South) Korean, Japanese Hiragana and Katakana (but *not* Kanji)) are written in such a way that the characters themselves are obviously matched up with a syllable or a specific number of syllables.  In that case, if you know how those languages work, you could theoretically use Python to break the writing up into syllables.

Otherwise, you'd need a dictionary, or some other compling platform that takes care of this.   Poke around [`nltk`](http://nltk.org/) and see what you can find.

Comment: With Japanese, you are going to have an issue with the fact that Kanji characters have two different readings, which can have different syllable counts.  For example, 山 could be either "san" or "yama".  In order to deal with this, you can't just look at the individual character...you have to figure out what actual word a set of Kanji characters spells.

Comment: “In English, syllables are pretty much independent of how the words are written” is true, but misleading.  For a huge number of English words, the number of syllables is equal to the number of vowels in the word.

Comment: @StevenBurnap You are correct, which is why I specifically excluded Kanji from my answer, and mentioned only Katakana and Hiragana.  Updated answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: @jwpat7 Having done a lot of computational linguistics, I don't agree with that assertion.  It's much more complicated than that, because there's also the question of what constitutes a vowel, distinguishing vowel digraphs from genuinely separate vowels, and accounting for differences in pronunciation.  Not only that, but it's far from clear where to split the syllable: is it `eq-ual` or `e-qual`? It may seem obvious, but it's really, really not.  And this of course doesn't begin to touch on the problems with English orthography, like the word `huge`--2 "vowels" written, but 1 syllable.

Comment: jdotjdot, you misconstrued what I wrote.  I meant that in most English text, the total number of syllables is within a few percent of the number of {a,e,i,o,u,y} letters.  Of course there are many words (eg, many one-syllable words ending in e) where number of syllables and number of vowels differ, and of course there are vowel digraphs and questionable vowels, but for most words it's a simple vowel per syllable.  Also, question does not ask about splitting into syllables, it asks about counting syllables.

Comment: Does anybody know where I could find a french python dictionary? For use in python in the same manner as CMUdict is used in python.

Comment: @jquadrin might want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @jdotjdot Unfortunately, nearly all written Japanese uses Kanji extensively, so unless you've got some preprocessor that converts (which would need a dictionary) you'd be out of luck for real world text.

Comment: @StevenBurnap It was really just intended as an example of when it might be possible to do so without a dictionary, and really not so relevant to OP's question.  Let's just say you win.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be argumentative, just to say it isn't a workable real-world solution for Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.  For some languages there might be, but if you don't have a dictionary you'd need knowledge of those languages' linguistic structure.  How words are divided into syllables varies from language to language.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't do it in a general way for all languages, because different languages render sounds to text differently.

For example, the Hungarian word "vagy" looks like 2 syllables to an English speaker, but it's only one. And the English word "bike" would naturally be read as 2 syllables by speakers of many other languages.

Furthermore, for English you probably can't do this very accurately without a dictionary anyway, because English has so much bizarre variation in its spelling. For example, we pronounce the "oe" in "poet" as two distinct syllables, but only one in "does".  This is probably true of some other languages as well.